# Labeling Google Cloud Dataflow job using Apache Beam

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am working on a Dataflow pipeline using Apache Beam to read some data streams and wondering how to label the Dataflow job in Google Cloud Platform. There exists method `void setLabels(Map<String, String> labels)` in the  `DataflowPipelineOptions`-class but I am not sure how to use the method.

Using `setLabels()` the following way is apparently wrong:

```
        PipelineOptionsFactory.register(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);

        Map<String, String> labels = null;
        labels.put("env", "dev");
        
        PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory
                .fromArgs(args)
                .withValidation()
                .as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class)
                .setLabels(labels);
    
        options.setRunner(DataflowRunner.class);
    
        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
```

I would appreciate some help regarding usage of `DataflowPipelineOptions` and labeling of a Dataflow job. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Setting fields in your pipeline options programmatically is a fine way to do this, and your code seems like it's the correct approach aside from a small issue in your snippet (setLabels returns void so you need to put it on a separate line you did with setRunner). What goes wrong when you try this approach? Is it a specific error, or do the labels not get applied to the Dataflow job?

Comment: Thank you, @DanielOliveira. You are right that `setLabel` returns void and that causes a problem the way my code is now. But `setLabel` is a method of `DataflowPipelineOptions` class and therefore called by that class´ object. How can I do that?

Comment: Changing `PipelineOptions options = ...` to `DataflowPipelineOptions options = ...` should let you do that. The `as()` method returns your pipeline options as the type specified so all you need to do is store it as that type.